# Loop in R to match and extract data from other sheet

Tags: r

I am newbie to R so please bear with me. I have two data frame dfA and dfB.

dfA

```
   Type
Test1 11000
11000 Test2
Test3 11000
11000 Test4
Test5 11001
Test6 11002
Test7 11003
Test8 11004
Test9 11004
Test10 11006
```

DfB

```
Asset NO    No
11000       1
11001       2
11002       3
11003       4
11004       5
11005       6
11006       7
11007       8
11008       9
11009      10
```

Desired Out Put

```
Type         No
Test1 11000   1
11000 Test2   1
Test3 11000   1
11000 Test4   1
Test5 11001   2
Test6 11002   3
Test7 11003   4
Test8 11004   5
Test9 11004   5
Test10 11006  7
```

I believe forloop and grepl is required.If some one can help me with how to pen down the forloop would be of great help.

Comment: is it normal that in `dfA` `Test2` and `Test4` are in the right-column and not in the left one ?

Comment: in dfA Type is a single column having the data 'Test1 11000'?

Comment: it would be best if you posted the outputs of `dput(dfA)` and `dput(dfB)` as to have a better idea of what your data looks like.

Comment: @etienne It is one line no column so Ideally one word '11000Test2'
'Test311000' and hence the reason to use grepl and search from second df   as the numbers are not in line need to use a search to match or else could have removed the initials and did a match.

Comment: @Hardik Yes it is single column

Comment: The definition of the regular expression is crucial here. Is there a blank in the words of `Type`, e.g., `'11000 Test2'`, `'Test3 11000'` or not as indicated in one of your comments, e.g., `'11000Test2'`, `'Test311000'`?

Comment: Or, does `Asset NO` _always_ consist of 5 digits?

Comment: @ArkadeepPaulChoudhury From your various comments I understand that your production data might look much more cluttered than the made-up sample data in your Q. Please, provide a more representative sample of your data.

Answer (score 1):

If `dfB$No` is just a row number, I would simply do

```
match(as.integer(sub(".*(\\b\\d+\\b).*", "\\1", dfA$Type)), dfB$AssetNO)
## [1] 1 1 1 1 2 3 4 5 5 7
```

This will catch only the integers within `dfA$Type` (bounded by a word bound) and then match back to `dfB$AssetNO`

---

Otherwise, with a small modification, you could do

```
indx <- match(as.integer(sub(".*(\\b\\d+\\b).*", "\\1", dfA$Type)), dfB$AssetNO)
dfB[indx, "No"]
## [1] 1 1 1 1 2 3 4 5 5 7
```

---

As a side note, your data seem to be messed up. You probably should try to record your data in a consistent format. This way, regex could be avoided and hence great boost in performance.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
Type <- c("Test1 11000","11000 Test2","Test3 11000","11000 Test4","Test5 11001",
          "Test6 11002","Test7 11003","Test8 11004","Test9 11004","Test10 11006")

Asset_NO <- seq(11000,11009,1)   
No <- seq(1,10,1)

dfA <- data.frame(Type)
dfB <- data.frame(Asset_NO,No)

split <- str_split(dfA$Type, " ")
v <- c(NULL)

for (i in 1:length(split)) {
  f <- sapply(split, "[",1)
  s <- sapply(split, "[",2)
  #v <- ifelse(grepl("Test",f), s, f)
   v <- ifelse(grepl("[a-zA-Z]",f), s, f) #As per the new cooment
}

dfA$Asset_NO <- v
dfA$Asset_NO <- as.numeric(dfA$Asset_NO)

m <- merge(dfA, dfB, by="Asset_NO")
m
```

Output

```
    Asset_NO         Type No
1     11000  Test1 11000  1
2     11000  11000 Test2  1
3     11000  Test3 11000  1
4     11000  11000 Test4  1
5     11001  Test5 11001  2
6     11002  Test6 11002  3
7     11003  Test7 11003  4
8     11004  Test8 11004  5
9     11004  Test9 11004  5
10    11006 Test10 11006  7
```

Comment: cannot use grepl as "test" as all the Type are not mentioned as Test this was just an example in real data itz all different. So basically need to do a search with the number so search the first number from dfB and match it with dfA and then get the output from column b of dfB and if no match then pick the 2nd number from 2nd df and so on....

Answer (score 0):

I first create a new column for `dfA` called `NEW`:

and use `gsub` to replace all the alphabet letters with empty string`""`. This gives me a vector of two numbers, but I look for the one that makes sense by sorting the numbers, one is an index the other one is the value of the column according to `Asset_NO` in `dfB`

```
dfA$NEW = NA
for(i in 1:nrow(dfA)){
    temp = as.numeric(strsplit(gsub("[[:alpha:]]", "", dfA$Type[i]), split = " ")[[1]])
    dfA$NEW[i] = (sort(temp, decreasing = T)[1])
}
```

I make sure that these are now all in numeric forms, so comparing apples and oranges.

```
dfB$Asset_NO = as.numeric(dfB$Asset_NO)
```

Then all I need to do is to merge them.

```
df_new = merge(x=dfA, y=dfB, by.x  ="NEW" , by.y="Asset_NO")[,-1]
print(df_new)

# Type No
# 1   Test1 11000  1
# 2   11000 Test2  1
# 3   Test3 11000  1
# 4   11000 Test4  1
# 5   Test5 11001  2
# 6   Test6 11002  3
# 7   Test7 11003  4
# 8   Test8 11004  5
# 9   Test9 11004  5
# 10 Test10 11006  7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the column `Asset_NO` in `dfB` using `gregexpr` and a simple `ifelse` statement and `merge` as follows,

```
dfA$Asset_NO <- ifelse(sapply(gregexpr('[A-Za-z]+', dfA$Type), '[', 1) > 1, 
                          gsub('\\s+.*', '', dfA$Type), gsub('.*\\s+', '', dfA$Type))

merge(dfA, dfB)

#   Asset_NO         Type No
#1     11000  Test1 11000  1
#2     11000  11000 Test2  1
#3     11000  Test3 11000  1
#4     11000  11000 Test4  1
#5     11001  Test5 11001  2
#6     11002  Test6 11002  3
#7     11003  Test7 11003  4
#8     11004  Test8 11004  5
#9     11004  Test9 11004  5
#10    11006 Test10 11006  7
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach using `data.table` and `stringr`:

```
library(data.table)
dfA[, Asset := as.integer(stringr::str_extract(Type, "(^\\d{5})|(\\d{5}$)"))]
dfB[dfA, on = "Asset", .(Type, No)]
#            Type No
# 1:  Test1 11000  1
# 2:  11000 Test2  1
# 3:  Test3 11000  1
# 4:  11000 Test4  1
# 5:  Test5 11001  2
# 6:  Test6 11002  3
# 7:  Test7 11003  4
# 8:  Test8 11004  5
# 9:  Test9 11004  5
#10: Test10 11006  7
#11:   Test111000  1
#12:   11000Test2  1
#13:   Test311000  1
#14:   11000Test4  1
#15:   Test511001  2
#16:   Test611002  3
#17:   Test711003  4
#18:   Test811004  5
#19:   Test911004  5
#20:  Test1011006  7
```

Please, note that all the answers differ in the regular expression used to extract the asset number from `Type`.  This is  due to the poor specification supplied in the original question.

The regular expression used here supposes that the asset number consists always of five digits and that `Type` either starts or ends with the asset number. This is independent of any word boundaries and thus works also in cases where no blanks are included in `Type`.

After assigning the extracted asset numbers to a new column `dfA` is joined with `dfB` on `Asset`.

### Discussion

I just realized that the OP has revealed important information in various comments:

> @etienne It is one line no column so Ideally one word '11000Test2' 'Test311000' and hence the reason to use grepl and search from second df as the numbers are not in line need to use a search to match or else could have removed the initials and did a match.

and

> cannot use grepl as "test" as all the Type are not mentioned as Test this was just an example in real data itz all different. So basically need to do a search with the number so search the first number from dfB and match it with dfA and then get the output from column b of dfB and if no match then pick the 2nd number from 2nd df and so on....

However, as long as the OP doesn't provide a more realistic sample of his production data and as long as the asset numbers can be extracted from `Type` unambigously by a regular expression there is no need to look up every given asset number if there is a match in `Type`.